# Access to javascript module Class/object from index.html

Tags: javascript, typescript, domcontentloaded, javascript-import

I defined Class in my javascript file...I imported that file into html page:

```
<script type="module" src="./js/controller.js"></script>
```

How can I now acces to classes inside of that js file?
I want to have something like this (in my html file):

```
<script>
  let app = null;
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    //Init app on DOM load
    app = new MyApp();
  });
</script>
```

But it doesn't work (I get Uncaught ReferenceError: MyApp is not defined)...If I include this DOMContentLoaded listener into end of my controller.js file, It works. But I lost reference to app variable this way (which I don't want)... Is there way to have reference to something defined in modules?

Most important reason why I want to have that reference is ability to access to my app object from google chrome console...

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code of *./js/controller.js*.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your class in js file from html in the following way-

My Home.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <script type="module">
        import { Car } from "./main.js";

        let obj= null;
        alert("Working! ");
        obj = new Car("Mini", 2001);
        obj.PrintDetails(); 

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            let obj2 = new Car("Merc", 2010);
            obj2.PrintDetails();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Lets try something <br></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

My main.js file:

```
export class Car {
constructor(name, year) {
  this.name = name;
  this.year = year;

}
PrintDetails() {
    console.log(" Name = "+ this.name);
    console.log(" year = "+ this.year);
}
```

}

Comment: But you didn't add you main.js file as module (look at my script type).

Comment: I have updated the code, I hope this works for you...